# Optimizar un listado de SQLServer en C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, timeout

tengo que listar aprox 900000 registros de una base de datos, y luego hacer un recorrido en C# con un FOR, pero al ser demasiados registros me aparece el error de tiempo de espera agotado.
¿Existe alguna manera de acelerar esto?
Este es mi SP en SQL: El resultado es de 870000 registros.

```
create proc spSNMMan_SP_Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño 
@mes int,
@año int
as
select (g.GUIA_DET_NRO_REF)'N° de Guía',
guia_det_fch_emi Fecha_Guia
from guia_detalle_nacional g WITH(NOLOCK)
where g.NWT_CON_IMG = 1 and
MONTH(guia_det_fch_emi)=@mes and
year(guia_det_fch_emi)=@año
```

Este es mi FOR en C#:

```
       void Listar() {
        try
        {
            CN_Guias guias = new CN_Guias();
            DateTime Hoy = DateTime.Today;
            string fecha_actual = Hoy.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            string mes, año;
            mes = txt_mes.Text;
            año = txt_anno.Text;
            if (txt_ruta.Text == "")
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Ingresar Ruta por favor.!!!");
                MessageBox.Show("Ingresar Ruta por favor.!!!", "Ingresar Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else if (txt_mes.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ingrese el Mes por favor.!!!", "Ingresar Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else if (txt_anno.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ingrese el Año por favor.!!!", "Ingresar Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
            else
            {

                int cantidad_imagen_db = guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño
                    (Convert.ToInt32(mes), Convert.ToInt32(año)).Rows.Count;
                pgb_cargando.Visible = true;
                pgb_cargando.Maximum = cantidad_imagen_db;
                pgb_cargando.Step = 1;
                pgb_cargando.Value = 0;

                //INICIO FOR
                btn_listar.Enabled = false;
                for (int o = 0; o < cantidad_imagen_db; o++) //Recorre la cantidad de Imagenes de la DB
                {
                    string nom_imagen_db = guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño
                    (Convert.ToInt32(mes), Convert.ToInt32(año)).Rows[o][0].ToString().TrimEnd(' ');

                    var ruta_imagen = Path.Combine(txt_ruta.Text, nom_imagen_db + ".tif");
                    if (!File.Exists(ruta_imagen))
                    {
                        string f_guia = guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño(Convert.ToInt32(mes),
                        Convert.ToInt32(año)).Rows[o][1].ToString();
                        objguias.InsertarGuiasValidadas(nom_imagen_db,
                        Convert.ToDateTime(f_guia), Convert.ToDateTime(fecha_actual), 0);}
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Se realizo la validación correctamente");
                btn_listar.Enabled = true;
                Limpiar();

                //FIN FOR
                //btn_validar.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
```

Si alguien tiene alguna idea que me pueda servir, agradeceré comparta su conocimiento.

Gracias.

Comment: recomendación es que verifiques si esa tabla tiene indice y nunca tu columna lo parsees mejor parsea el valor que vas a colocar ya que si lo sigues haciendo haras que tenga bloqueos en la base. has ese mismo for por tu base y mira cuanto demora y mira si tienes bloqueos

Comment: ¿Cuanto tiempo está demorando el sp en devolver el resultado? Sospecho que es el SP el que está tardando antes de entrar al FOR. Además, aplicar funciones a los campos que se utilizan como criterios del where mata los posibles índices que hayan, la consulta ya no es sargable.

Comment: que hace el metodo guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño???? decime que ahi adentro no hace la consulta cada vez que lo llamas? y si no, donde hace la consulta? o sea, que linea tira el error???

Comment: Si tienes acceso al procedimiento, deberías agregar soporte para paginar los registros, usando `LIMIT` y `OFFSET` en sql y de esa manera procesar en lotes. Evitas el timeout y además cargar la tabla completa en memoria.

Comment: Hola a todos; **@PieroDev**, la tabla si tiene indices, justamente de esos campos. Al ejecutar el SP desde SQLSERVER demora 20 segundos(o aveces un poco más). **@JYass**, respecto al WHERE, los requiero como parametros  de MES y AÑO. ¿Que me recomiendas?. **@gbianchi**, el SP me sirve para listar datos en un rango de mes y año determinando. Luego este es llamado desde mi formulario en C#. Respecto al error suele darse cuando ejecuto el programa o aveces comienza a hacer el **FOR** y nunca termina.

Comment: Vuelvo a hacer la pregunta. que es Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño?? un metodo?? una propiedad?? donde haces el query????

Comment: **@KarelTamayo**, me suena interesante lo que comentas, es posible me pases un ejemplo o la modificación de mi SP para realizar las pruebas. Gracias.

Comment: Decime por dios que no es un metodo que ejecuta el SP cada vez que lo llamas...

Comment: **@gbianchi**, pensé que te referias al SP.  Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño es un objeto que almacena un Datatable, este lo llamo desde mi clase  CN_Guias guias = new CN_Guias();   -> guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño
                        (Convert.ToInt32(mes), Convert.ToInt32(año)).Rows.Count;

Comment: **@gbianchi**, en resumidas cuentas ese FOR trae el listado que se aloja en el Strore Procedure. Me puede dar una idea de como mejorar esto por favor.

Comment: @GonzaloRios lo que pregunta gbianchi es si dentro del método se ejecuta el SP, y por consiguiente, se ejecuta 1800000 veces el SP (porque hay dos llamadas al método en cada iteración), cada vez 20 segundos aprox, según dices. Lo ideal sería ejecutar una sola vez el SP, y luego trabajar el FOR con el datatable, sin llamar al SP nuevamente en cada iteración

Comment: si es un objeto, porque le pasas parametros a cada rato!!!! mostra ese objeto, metodo por favor.. todo tu problema esta ahi como dice @JYass.. y es peor, porque lo llamas montones de veces!!!

Comment: Clase que contiene el SP : comando.Connection = conexion.AbrirConexion();
                //comando.CommandText = "SP_Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño";
                comando.CommandText = "spSNMMan_SP_Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño";
                comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mes", mes);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@año", año);
                leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
                tabla.Load(leer);
                return tabla;

Comment: Esta es la de mi clase negocio: public DataTable Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño(int mes, int año)
        {
            CD_Guias objetoCD = new CD_Guias();
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            tabla = objetoCD.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño(mes,año);
            return tabla;
        }

Comment: Me pueden indicar, como ejecutaria solo uan vez el SP, y como recorreria con el FOR sin tener que llamar al SP a cada rato ?? por favor.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho es peor.. llama 2 veces por cada iteracion... o sea.. hace 1.800.000 consultas a la db... con razon le da timeout...

Comment: @GonzaloRios el invocar solo una vez al procedure y luego iterar sus items te lo respondo en el ejemplo

Comment: @gbianchi, si es cierto, el tema es que además hace una operación física sobre archivos, eso no lo había visto al comienzo, por lo que si bien se podría, descarto la idea de llevar toda la lógica al servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modo de complemento de la respuesta de @Leandro Tuttini, puedes modificar la consulta para no aplicar funciones del lado izquierdo del where. 20 segundos es mucho tiempo para devolver 900000 registros y puede ser optimizable. Cuando aplicas una función a una columna, se vuelve NO SARGEABLE, lo que significa que no se puede aprovechar los indices que haya, pues se necesita recorrer todas las filas para poder aplicarle la función en la columna indicada. Pues revisar estos [consejos de optimizacion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/apinedo/2007/01/24/mejorar-el-rendimiento-de-queries-en-sql-server/).

Para eliminar las funciones en tu consulta, veo que necesitas las guías de un mes y año especifico. Es decir, si necesitamos las guias del mes pasado, el rango de fechas contemplaría del 01/10/2018 al 31/10/2018.

Entonces, podríamos dejar la query de la siguiente manera:

```
create proc spSNMMan_SP_Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño 
@fechaInicio date,
@fechaFin date
as

select (g.GUIA_DET_NRO_REF)'N° de Guía',
guia_det_fch_emi Fecha_Guia
from guia_detalle_nacional g WITH(NOLOCK)
where g.NWT_CON_IMG = 1 and
guia_det_fch_emi >=@fechaInicio and
guia_det_fch_emi <=@fechaFin
```

De esta manera, evitamos aplicar una función a nuestras condiciones en el where y con un índice en el campo `guia_det_fch_emi` el rendimiento debería ser notable. Ahora, ¿de donde obtenemos la fecha de inicio y la fecha de fin de mes?

Voy a utilizar el código que propuso Leandro, definiremos ambas fechas y las enviaremos como parámetros:

```
string fechaInicio = "1/"+mes.ToString()+"/"+año.ToString();
DateTime fechaPrimerDia = Convert.ToDateTime(fechaInicio);
DateTime fechaUltimoDia = fechaPrimerDia.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
DataTable dtImagenes = guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño(fechaPrimerDia,fechaUltimoDia);
```

Y por supuesto, se debe modificar el método Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño para que reciba fechas en lugar de enteros.

Comment: ok, perfecto. Lo aplicare y realizare las pruebas. En unos minutos detallare los resultados. Muchas gracias. **@JYass**

Answer (score 4):

El problema esta en que en cada iteracion de loop estas invocando el procedure

```
string nom_imagen_db = guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño
                (Convert.ToInt32(mes), Convert.ToInt32(año)).Rows[o][0].ToString()
```

para tomar un solo registro, eso es una pesima idea y los realizas varias veces para ambas columna

Podrias utilizar el `foreach` para iterar cada item de la lista y no solo su indice

```
void Listar() {
    try
    {
        CN_Guias guias = new CN_Guias();

        string mes = txt_mes.Text;
        string año = txt_anno.Text;

        if (txt_ruta.Text == "")
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Ingresar Ruta por favor.!!!");
            MessageBox.Show("Ingresar Ruta por favor.!!!", "Ingresar Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return;
        }
        if (txt_mes.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese el Mes por favor.!!!", "Ingresar Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return;
        }
        if (txt_anno.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese el Año por favor.!!!", "Ingresar Datos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            return;
        }


        DataTable dtImagenes = guias.Listar_Guias_xMes_xAño(Convert.ToInt32(mes), Convert.ToInt32(año));

        pgb_cargando.Visible = true;
        pgb_cargando.Maximum = cantidad_imagen_db;
        pgb_cargando.Step = 1;
        pgb_cargando.Value = 0;

        btn_listar.Enabled = false;

        foreach (DataRow row in dtImagenes.Rows)
        {
            string nom_imagen_db = row["N° de Guía"].ToString().TrimEnd(' ');

            var ruta_imagen = Path.Combine(txt_ruta.Text, nom_imagen_db + ".tif");
            if (!File.Exists(ruta_imagen))
            {
                string f_guia = row["Fecha_Guia"].ToString();
                objguias.InsertarGuiasValidadas(nom_imagen_db, 
                                                Convert.ToDateTime(f_guia), 
                                                DateTime.Now, 0);
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Se realizo la validación correctamente");
        btn_listar.Enabled = true;

        Limpiar();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Adapte el codigo para que veas como se soluciona usando

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtImagenes.Rows){ ..
```

Ademas puedes acceder a los campos po su nombre, aunque aconsejaria definas algo ma estandar por ejemplo cambiar "N° de Guía" por "NroGuia" y "Fecha_Guia" solo por "FechaGuia"

Comment: Una hora peleandosela para dejarla servida ;) +1

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono.